# "Incorrect HTTP method" when trying to insert documents into elasticsearch index

Tags: json, elasticsearch, curl

I have a bunch of json docs in `my_docs.json`. I want to insert them into `http://localhost:9200/twitter`, where `twitter` is my index.

I tried: `curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/twitter' -d @my_docs.json` but that returned an error:

```
{"error":"Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/twitter] and method [POST], allowed: [DELETE, PUT, GET, HEAD]","status":405}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response from Elasticsearch has your answer.

```
{
    "error":"Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/twitter] and method [POST], allowed: [DELETE, PUT, GET, HEAD]",
    "status":405
}
```

You should use `PUT` instead of `POST`.